# Mongodb operate on timestamp in long

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, timestamp

In our database it uses NumberLong to store timestamp. The question is which javascript function I can use to operate on the timestamp in mongodb shell?

For example, find out the time in millis of the next day of time NumberLong(1330828762699) and the beginning of the current day.

Comment: Can you use the `Date` object?

Comment: Do you mean `var date = new Date(timestamp)` and do operation on the date object? I am thinking of it, just want to see if there are other shortcuts to go

Comment: Exactly. It's been a while since I've used MongoDB but if you can use the `Date` object I'd use that.

Comment: Then it will probably need to write some UDF routines in javascript. Do you know where I can save the js functions I've created in the shell?

Comment: I don't think you can save the in the shell, but you can load them on startup using `mongo --shell yourfile.js`. For an example of such a helper, see https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/uuidhelpers.js

Comment: You can save scripts server-side using the system.js collection: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution however if you plan on using these scripts often you're probably better off saving them in your own version-control system.

Comment: thanks menumosyn and matulef, both your answers makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) "new Date()" in the mongo shell gets promoted to ISODate() so you can use the methods on that;

```
> new Date(1330828762699)
ISODate("2012-03-04T02:39:22.699Z")
> new Date(1330828762699).getMilliseconds()
699
```

2) With regards to timestamps on documents, did you know that there's a built-in create date you can use?

```
> ObjectId("5020317b92c3d21cb851fa1a").getTimestamp()
ISODate("2012-08-06T21:04:59Z")
```

3) I would take a look at the 2.2 aggregate framework for manipulating your data. It has some useful date functions you may be able to employ to make useful time-based queries over your data;

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#date-operators